# What is the proper way to setup and use php-resque?

Tags: php, resque

I am trying to use [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) to queue and execute ffmpeg conversions on my server. I understand broadly how it should work, but I am having some trouble with the details and can not find any tutorials. Specifically, I don't understand where I should place my job classes, and how to give the classes to my workers and start my workers. The read me only says "Getting your application underway also includes telling the worker your job classes, by means of either an autoloader or including them."

Hopefully someone can outline the overall structure of using php-resque.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can put your job classes where you want. It'll depend on your application structure.

## How to create a job class

For example, let's suppose the class `VideoConversion`, used for the ffmpeg conversion.

```
class VideoConversion {

    public function perform() {
        // The code for video conversion here
    }

}
```

In your main application, before using php-resque, let's say you have something like that

```
public function uploadVideo() {
    // Upload and move the video to a temp folder
    // Convert the video
}
```

And you want to enqueue the 'convert video' part. Let's just queue it to the `convert` queue:

```
public function uploadVideo() {
    // Upload and move the video to a temp folder
    // Let's suppose you need to convert a 'source video' to a 'destination video'
    Resque::enqueue('convert', 'VideoConversion', array('origine-video.avi', 'destination-video.avi'));
}
```

When queuing the job, we passed the path to the source and destination video to the VideoConversion class. You can pass other argument, it'll depend on how your VideoConversion class is written.

A worker will then poll the `convert` queue, and execute the `VideoConversion` job. What the worker will do is to instantiate the VideoConversion class, and execute the `perform()` method.

The job arguments (`array('origine-video.avi', 'destination-video.avi')`), third argument when queueing the job with `Resque::enqueue`, will be available inside the `perform()` method via `$this->args`.

```
# VideoConversion.php
class VideoConversion
{
    public function perform() {
    // $this->args == array('origine-video.avi', 'destination-video.avi');
    // Convert the video
}
```

### Find your job classes

The `VideoConversion` class can be put anywhere, but you have to tell your workers where to find it.
There's multiple ways to do that

#### Put you jobs classes in the include_path

In your .htaccess or the apache config, add the directory containing all your job classes to the include path. Your workers will automatically find them.

Main issue with this method is that all your jobs classes must be in the same folder, and that all your job classes are available everywhere.

#### Tell each worker where to find your job classes

When starting the worker, use the `APP_INCLUDE` argument to point to the job classes 'autoloader'.

```
APP_INCLUDE=/path/to/autoloader.php QUEUE=convert php resque.php
```

The above command will start a new worker, polling the queue named `convert`. 
We're also passing the file */path/to/autoloader.php* to the worker. ([see here to learn to start a worker](http://www.kamisama.me/2012/10/12/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-4-managing-worker/))

Technically, the worker will include that file with `include '/path/to/autoloader.php';`.

You can then tell the workers how to find your job classes:

**Use basic include**

In the '/path/to/autoloader.php':

```
include /path/to/VideoConversion.php
include /path/to/anotherClass.php
...
```

**Use an autoloader**

Use php autoloader to load your job classes.

**Use `set_include_path()`**

```
set_include_path('path/to/job');
```

That way, your jobs are in the `include_path` just for this worker.

### Closing thought

`APP_INCLUDE` is binded to the worker you're starting. If you're starting another worker, use `APP_INCLUDE` again. You can use a different file for each worker.

You can also design your job classes to execute more than one job. There's a [tutorial](http://www.kamisama.me/2012/10/13/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-5-creating-jobs/) explaining how to do that. It covers from the basic of a queue system to how to use and implement it.

If it's still not enough, take a look at resque documentation. php-resque API is exactly the same. Only difference is that Resque job classes are written in Ruby, whereas php-resque's one are in php.

Comment: Hi Kamisama,

I went thru your blog article related to Background job and they were excellent.

I'm following the same steps on Windows7. Jobs are queued properly. I can see it from Redis console. But when I run the Resque command, Jobs are popped (count goes down in Redis Console) but job is empty. I checked this by putting fwrite in actual PHP-Resque library.

Resque.php Class's pop method is fetching item ($item) but it is always empty.

Any idea what can be wrong? Does this have something to do with Windows OS?

Thanks.

Comment: So the Redis pop command is always returning null ? Check that php in cli mode is configured properly to use redis.

Comment: @Kamisama thx for your useful tutorial series. How can tell resque worker to process only one job at a time for a given queue?

Comment: Forgot to mention that my application i used a symfony bundle BccResqueBundle

Comment: When enqueuing, shouldn't it say ```Resque::enqueue('convert', 'VideoConversion', array('origine-video.avi', 'destination-video.avi'));``` rather than default?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check out following tutorial on how to use resque with phalcon.
http://www.mehuldoshi.in/background-jobs-phalcon-resque/