# How can I define a job in php resque for redis?

Tags: php, redis

I am new for redis and currently I am using PHP resque for redis. How can I define a job in php resque?

Comment: Maybe this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814445/what-is-the-proper-way-to-setup-and-use-php-resque](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814445/what-is-the-proper-way-to-setup-and-use-php-resque) would help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queueing Jobs

Jobs are queued as follows:

```
require_once 'lib/Resque.php';

// Required if redis is located elsewhere
Resque::setBackend('localhost:6379');

$args = array(
    'name' => 'Chris'
);
```

Resque::enqueue('default', 'My_Job', $args);
Defining Jobs

Each job should be in it's own class, and include a perform method.

```
class My_Job
{
    public function perform()
    {
        // Work work work
        echo $this->args['name'];
    }
}
```

When the job is run, the class will be instantiated and any arguments will be set as an array on the instantiated object, and are accessible via $this->args.

Any exception thrown by a job will result in the job failing - be careful here and make sure you handle the exceptions that shouldn't result in a job failing.

Comment: Avinash,

I'm following the same steps on Windows7. Jobs are queued properly. I can see it from Redis console. But when I run the Resque command, Jobs are popped (count goes down in Redis Console) but job is empty. I checked this by putting fwrite in actual PHP-Resque library.

Resque.php Class's pop method is fetching item ($item) but it is always empty.

Any idea what can be wrong? Does this have something to do with Windows OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has changed in the newest version of PHP-resque, released 13 October 2012. According to the changelog, "Wrap job arguments in an array to improve compatibility with ruby resque."

which means if you've upgraded to PHP-Resque 1.2 you will access jobs from $args[0].